# DragGesture doesn't work with custom Layout to dynamically locate subview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a custom layout, where I want to originally place subviews at absolute points on the Y axis using a **`LayoutValueKey`**. I am also trying to implement a **`DragGesture`** to allow for changing the location of these subviews by updating the passed value. Here is a simplified code:

```
struct TestLayout: View {
    
    @State var Y: CGFloat = 200
    @State var baseY: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
                
            CustomLayout(size: geometry.size) {
                Circle()
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .locationY(Y)
                
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                Y = baseY + value.translation.height
                                print(Y)
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                baseY = Y
                            }
                    )
            }

        }
    }
}


struct CustomLayout: Layout {
    
    let size: CGSize
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        return size
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        
        let x = CGFloat(200)
        
        for subview in subviews {
            if let y = subview[LocationY.self] {
                subview.place(at: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), proposal: .unspecified)
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct LocationY: LayoutValueKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
}


extension View {
    func locationY(_ value: CGFloat?) -> some View {
        layoutValue(key: LocationY.self, value: value)
    }
}


#Preview {
    TestLayout()
}
```

When I run this code in the simulator  and while I drag the view it jumps erratically up and down. When run and drag on a physical device (iPhone XS Max), the view doesn’t even move at all, and my Mac starts to heat up significantly. The **`print`** statement within **`.onChanged`** shows how the `Y` value is fluctuating wildly.

I guess the problem is in **`CustomLayout`** or in the way it is structured.  How can I modify the code to achieve smooth dragging and accurate positioning within **`CustomLayout`**? I specifically need to use **`CustomLayout`** for various reasons, so I am not looking for alternatives like **`VStack`** or **`ZStack`** with offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you've got a gesture within a custom `Layout` that dynamically moves original location of a subview it messes the applied gesture itself, moving it with the subview. This messes with `value.translation.height` and causes the subview to jump as you drag it. This doesn't happen with `.offset` because this way you change only the relative position of a subview, not original. So I moved the gesture outside the custom layout. This way, it works as expected and lets you dynamically change the original location. Just make sure other gestures don't interfere.

```
struct TestLayout: View {
    
    @State var Y: CGFloat = 200
    @State var baseY: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
                
            CustomLayout(size: geometry.size) {
                Circle()
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .locationY(Y)
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        Y = baseY + value.translation.height
                        print(Y)
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        baseY = Y
                    }
            )

        }
    }
}
```

If you have multiple subviews in the custom layout, you can use `value.startLocation` in the drag gesture to figure out which subview you're dragging.